# Why did Palpatine and Tarkin try Ahsoka Tano's trial?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Why did Palpatine and Admiral Tarkin try [Ahsoka Tano's trial](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Trial_of_Ahsoka_Tano)?

Shouldn't the Chancellor and a Fleet Admiral have more important things to do than play judge and lawyer?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that Admiral Tarkin's speech (from the [same episode](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wrong_Jedi)) answers this pretty nicely.

- The general belief is that a Jedi trial would be unfairly biased in her favour
- She's a high profile defendant and given the potential for a bad press, she needs to be held to account by a judge and prosecutor that are believed (by the Senate) to be of unimpeachable character.

> **Tarkin :** *"The Senate believes that an internal Jedi trial would seem biased.
>   Therefore, the Senate asks that the Council expel Ahsoka Tano from the
>   Jedi Order so that she may be put to a Republic military tribunal,
>   where she will receive more impartial judgment."*

Comment: Plenty of societies, especially those that are (publicly or secretly) corrupt, have politicians serve judicial roles.  Especially since the quote above mentions a "military tribunal," where things are at best done by different rules, and at worst a piece of theater before an assumed conviction.

Comment: This is a conjecture with no basis. Do you believe in a civilized society a high profile trial such as this would be presided over  and tried by 2 people she has an active  working relationship with and no judicial credentials?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a reason that Palpatine and Tarkin are directly involved in the trial process. Does anyone know of a reference in material, not a guess?

Comment: @Richard It still doesn't make sense for Palpatine and Tarkin to try her, no matter what speech he gave.

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker - The senate see Palpatine and Tarkin as neutral arbiters. That's the answer plain and simple. The fact that you think this is a bad thing (in-universe) is irrelevant.

Comment: I still think its a good question.

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker - The question itself is fine. The problem is a) that the answer is **in the question** and b) That you're unwilling to accept that. Let the downvotes be your guide.

Comment: @Richard it still doesn't make sense for people she has worked with to try her

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker - I refer you to my earlier comment. This trial is taking place **at the direct request of the Senate**. They've asked for someone with *unimpeachable* credentials (Palpatine) to arbitrate and someone with sufficient seniority to command respect but no obvious axe to grind (Tarkin) to act as prosecutor. Notably the jury is also comprised of senators. The alternative is an internal investigation by the Jedi (unacceptable to the Senate) or a criminal trial (inappropriate since the Jedi are members of the Judicial Dept).